# Ignore commands when compiling

Tags: macros

I have defined some custom commands that I use for TODO-notes. If I write a note i use the command `\stefan{}`.

Now I want to define a new command, for example `\supervisor{}`.

I need a way to get LaTeX to ignore either one of the commands. When `\supervisor` is disabled I will want the `\stefan` command to get compiled.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this from the command line.  Take @PeterGrill's basic document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\stefan}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\supervisor}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}
Some text. \supervisor{Correct this!!}

Some text. \stefan{Correct this also!!}
\end{document}
```

This will give you all the comments.  Then create a `.sty` file, which could be as simple as:

```
% disable various comments
\renewcommand{\stefan}[1]{}
```

Then, when you want to 'hide' various comments, compile from the command line:

```
pdflatex "\AtBeginDocument{\input{mycomments.sty}}\input{masterfile.tex}"
```

Or compile normally when you want all comments to appear.

Or, perhaps even more elegantly, you could implement @PeterGrill's suggestion:

Use the following (say) file `commentcommands.sty`:

```
\ifdefined\SupervisorMode
% re-define various commenting commands to do nothing
\renewcommand{\stephan}[1]{}
% ... etc., etc.
\fi
```

Then load `commentcommands.sty` *after* the original comment commands in the master file:

```
\usepackage{commentcommands}
```

Then, when you want to 'disable' the various commands in the document you hand to your supervisor, run the command as:

```
pdflatex "\def\Supervisormode{}\input{masterfile.tex}"
```

This does have the advantage of a clearer call to `pdflatex`, which you could also put into a makefile if you were so inclined.

Comment: Excellent idea. A slight implement would be to use `\ifdefined\SupervisorMode
 \renewcommand{\stefan}[1]{}
\fi` in the `.sty` file and then use `def\SupervisorMode{}` on the command line.  Same idea, but you don't need two files, and the command line is more readable.

Comment: @PeterGrill -- Very true.  Your suggestion is a clear improvement, so I added it to the original answer.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand you correctly, one way would be to use `\ifdefined\supervisor` to test if `\supervisor` was defined, and if so redefine the `\stefan` macro:

[image]

### Notes:

- If you are using the `todonotes` package, you can use `\usepackage[disable]{todonotes}`

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\stefan}[1]{\textcolor{red}{Stefan's Comment: #1}}

\newcommand{\supervisor}[1]{}


\begin{document}
Some text. \stefan{Correct this!!}

\ifdefined\supervisor
    \renewcommand{\stefan}[1]{}
\fi

Some text. \stefan{Correct this also!!}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Yes, I am using the todonotes package. The problem with the disable option, is that it will disable every todonote in the document. I am working in a team on a project where we have a superviser assigned. Each member of the team have their own \name command to write a todo note. Whenever we want to turn in our document for comments by our supervisor, we do not want our todo notes to be visible. So we need a way to disable our own notes where we will still be able to write a note for our supervisor. I hope it makes a little more sense with my explanation.

Comment: Ok, but does the rest of the answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

You could use some boolean too.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@supervisor 
\newcommand\stefan[1]{\if@supervisor\else#1\fi}
\newcommand\supervisor[1]{\if@supervisor#1\fi}

% toggle supervisor mode
\newcommand\supervisormode{\@supervisortrue}
\newcommand\notsupervisormode{\@supervisorfalse}
\notsupervisormode

\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \supervisormode
  \stefan{This is stefan comment}
  \supervisor{This is supervisor comment}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: The code seems faulty: the @-commands should be enclosed between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`; a couple of `\newcommand` are missing.

Comment: Thank you for the remark. I didn't plan to give minimal example. I have changed the source.

Comment: Having a complete example is surely better, if feasible. The problem with `@` is recurrent, because people not acquainted with LaTeX programming may not be aware that `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are necessary.